# SSRS to Excel missing images and header when access via url

Tags: .net, excel, reporting-services, header, export

I am loading an SSRS report from an intranet site. When I go to the SSRS Report Manager and export the document to Excel it exports with all the items.

However when I do the same thing but through the web page I am missing some headers and images.

Here is my C# code

```
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer rview = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer();
                    rview.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(uri);
                    rview.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/T200/MiscAsset";

                    //For the ReportServerCredentials public class CustomReportCredentials must be added to the code
                    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.IReportServerCredentials irsc = new CustomReportCredentials(user, pass, domain);
                    rview.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = irsc;

                    if (_mode == null)
                    {
                        _mode = "PDF";
                    }

                    string deviceInfo, mimeType, encoding, extention;
                    string[] streamaids;
                    Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] warnings;
                    deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo>" + "<SimplePageHeaders>True</SimplePageHeaders>" + "</DeviceInfo>";
                    byte[] bytes = rview.ServerReport.Render(_mode, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extention, out streamaids, out warnings);
                    Response.Clear();

                    if (_mode == "PDF")
                    {
                        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=MiscAsset.pdf");
                    }
                    else if (_mode == "excel")
                    {
                        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=MiscAsset.xls");
                    }
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    Response.OutputStream.Flush();
                    Response.OutputStream.Close();
                    Response.Flush();
                    Response.Close();
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve it? What problems did you run in to, what info did you get during debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Are the images embedded in the report, or external? If they are external you need to ensure that the when viewed in the web page the user has necessary permissions to view the external images as well.

As for the headers, your code is setting SimplePageHeaders = True. This means that when the report is exported to Excel, the report header is rendered as the Excel page header and not as part of the worksheet. Try setting this to False.